# Creating New Arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

My goal is simple. I'd like to be able to take user input from 4 edittext fields, with ids of et1-4, and put them into an array named `aSummary1[] = {et1, et2, et3, et4};`. The four fields are different data types, two being words, one numbers, and one a password. This will all be displayed in a `ListView`. This part I can do. The part I can't figure out is if I want to add a new row in the `ListView`, I'd like to create a new string array, let's say `aSummary2[]` with different values, but the same parameters: `{word, word, number, password};`, then `aSummary3[]` and so on and so forth.

How would one go about doing this? Or if there is a better way, how would I assign variables and strings to list entries with no limit. For instance, with list entry x comes variables w y and z assigned to x, but with variable a comes b c and e, and with q comes r s and t.

Comment: Why Array? Why not object of a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a growing array..... Better go with `Collections`, its more `flexible`, and **unlike arrays, you don't initialize it at the time of its declaration.**

First Consider making a Pojo

```
public class Summary {

    private String str1;
    private String str2;
    private int number;
    private String password;



    public Summary(String str1, String str2, int number, String password) {

        this.str1 = str1;
        this.str2 = str2;
        this.number = number;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getStr1() {
        return str1;
    }

    public String getStr2() {
        return str2;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


}



 }
```

Now consider another class from where you **initialize this class object and store then in an** `ArrayList`.

```
public class Test{

public static ArrayList<Summary> arList = new ArrayList<Summary>();
private Summary sObj;

   public void fillMe(String p1, String p2, int p3, String p4){


           arList.add(new sObj(p1, p2, p3, p4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, the better solution will be to create a class containing all required fields, for example:

```
public class Summary {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private String field4;
}
```

And then store objects of this class inside an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Summary> summaries = new ArrayList<Summary>();
```

When you need to create another object of this type, just call:

```
Summary summary = new Summary();
// initialize fields
summaries.add(summary);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I want to call a specific variable from a specific location, eg. aSummary1[0] or aSummary14[3], how would I do that?

Comment: @Adam, Just call summaries.get(position)

Comment: The position would increase by 4 every time. The password would be at summaries.get(3) for the first password, but the second would be summaries.get(7). The twelfth password would be at summaries.get(47).

Comment: @Adam, You're not right. Password should be just a field of a Summary object, means to get first password you should get first item of summaries and retrieve its password.